# sudo with dash gives bad substitution

Tags: sudo, dash-shell

I tried to access a newly installed system via Emacs' Tramp the way I do it with all my other system:

```
C-x C-f /ssh:server|sudo:root@server:/etc/network/interfaces
```

This command timed out. After some investigation I found out that `sudo` and `dash` seem to be incompatible, although my `sudoers` is pretty simple:

```
# grep -P -v '^(#.*)?$' /etc/sudoers
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

When I use a normal shell like Bash the following command works fine:

```
env SHELL=/bin/bash sudo -u root -s -H
```

But when I use the dash, to which /bin/sh is linked to, the following command

```
env SHELL=/bin/sh sudo -u root -s -H
```

generates an endless loop

```
/bin/sh: 0: Bad substitution
/bin/sh: 0: Bad substitution
/bin/sh: 0: Bad substitution
/bin/sh: 0: Bad substitution
/bin/sh: 0: Bad substitution
...
```

which can only be stopped by `kill -9`.

I wish to do `apt-get purge dash` but the OS insists on keeping it.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I did it:

```
cd /bin
rm sh
ln -s bash sh
apt-get purge dash
apt-mark hold dash
```

The machine is still booting.